# eslint vscode plugin is not producing warnings for hooks

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, eslint

I created a react app with `npx create-react-app my-app` and did a yarn install. Added the following to App.js:

```
const a = () => 1,
  b = () => 2,
  c = () => 3;

function App() {
  const wut = useMemo(() => {
    return { a: a(), b: b(), c: c() };
  }, [a]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(a(), b(), c());
  }, [a]);
```

Yarn start will give me warnings but vscode does not.

I added `.eslintrc.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {
    "react/prop-types": [0],
    "no-console": [0],
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have the following code in a clean create-react-app:

```
function App(props) {
  const {a,b,c}=props;
  const wut = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("this should not happen multiple times");
    return { a: a(), b: b(), c: c() };
  }, [a]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(a(), b(), c());
  }, [a]);
```

Then removing the `.eslintrc.js` would give me the `React Hook useMemo has missing dependencies:` warning and the option to auto fix it.

When I have the `.eslintrc.js` in project root directory I get the error `Definition for rule 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' was not found.` this is because the .eslintrc.js was missing a plugin and `plugins: ["react", "react-hooks"],` solved it.

However; now the rule is off by default so it won't warn, needed to explicitly add the rule and set it to warn (or error) in the .eslintrc.js:

```
  rules: {
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"
  }
```

Comment: When you adding `eslintrc.js` it overrides the default configuration

Comment: @DennisVash I understand, what I do not understand is that without eslintrc it will warn (so will warn by default). With an eslintrc that doesn't specify what to do with the hook rule it will not warn (suggesting that default changed).

Comment: On overriding the default is "there is no rules" then you need specify whatever you want.

Comment: Notice that there are rules of overriding, everything documented on CRA site

Comment: @DennisVash I have no rule specified for `no-unused-vars` but it will warn so that is on by default. But the `exhaustive-deps` rule is on when there is no eslintrc (so **on** by default) but not on when there is a eslintrc with no value for `exhaustive-deps` (so **off** by default)

Answer (score 6):

The [list of rules for `react/recommended`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react#user-content-list-of-supported-rules) doesn't include `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

You likely didn't install [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks).

It includes a note:

> Note: If you're using Create React App, please wait for a corresponding release of react-scripts that includes this rule instead of adding it directly.

What version of c-r-a are you using? In theory it was added via [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5997).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working with yarn but vscode gives me: `Definition for rule 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' was not found` Uninstalled and installed ESLint plugin and ran `yarn add eslint-plugin-react-hooks --dev` but the problem persist.

Comment: How is your VS Code setup running ESLint? E.g., the (more or less defacto) plugin has a `eslint.lintTask.options` setting--you might need to point it at sthng it knows how to read. No idea if it would read a JS file w/ an export like that.

Comment: Solved it by changing the `.eslintlintrc.js`: `plugins: ["react", "react-hooks"],`. It also worked without an `.eslintrc.js`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using TypeScript, so the answer for me was to add the following to my VSCode settings:

```
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
```